# Postman not sending header key

Tags: api, postman, request-headers

I'm using Postman 9.8.3 on a test server for GET and POST.
I check security using a key in header.

While the GET calls work fine, the POST call can't read the key from header:
[image]

I also tried to add the key using a Pre-request Script, but no use:

```
pm.request.headers.add({
  key: "MyKey",
  value: "MyValue"
});
```

But in my Postman client on my PC it works fine, both adding the key in the Header form or using a Pre-request script, both GET and POST!

Did someone had the same problem?